# text file question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have text file that with the following structure:

```
test\n 
1\n
2\n
@/@/@/\n
test2 \n
223\n
44\n
@/@/@/\n
```

I can read it in array successfuly , but the line `@/@/@/` is separator. I want to divide the `NSArray` to sub arrays at the separator.

Any suggestion how to solve that?

I also need to modify certain section.

Best regards

Comment: "NSArray to sub arrays at the separator" Can you explain ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read it in as a NSString then

```
NSArray *chunks = [string componentsSeparatedByString: @"@/@/@/"];
```

Comment: can I modify certain part of text file , instead of rewrite the whole text again

Comment: Easiest thing to do will be to modify the read-in string and then write it back to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Use componentsSeparatedByString method.You can store the value obtained in an Array.